# strpos command breaking php program

Tags: php

I have been working on a madlibs program, and it has been breaking for no reason it seems like.
 I take user input from an html form. I am trying to check if the user input is valid. In order for the data to be valid, the data must NOT contain a space, or any punctuation character. I am not sure if I should use the strpos command, or preg_match. Anyway I am able to get to the first if statement, and it breaks. I have used multiple variations of this command, and no matter what I do my code seems to break. All I am trying to do is check if this consolidated string contains a single char. It seems simple enough, but I cannot seem to find the issue. Any responses would be greatly appreciated. I can post the code from my html page, but the problem does not lie in that code.

```
<?php
//Michael Keller
//Project1

//Variables
$stringFirstVerb = $_POST["stringFirstVerb"];       
$stringSecondVerb = $_POST["stringSecondVerb"];   
$stringThirdVerb = $_POST["stringThirdVerb"];        
$stringFirstNoun = $_POST["stringFirstNoun"];      
$stringSecondNoun = $_POST["stringSecondNoun"];     
$stringThirdNoun = $_POST["stringThirdNoun"];   
$stringFirstAdj = $_POST["stringFirstAdj"];    
$stringSecondAdj = $_POST["stringSecondAdj"];
$stringThirdAdj = $_POST["stringThirdAdj"];          
$stringParagraph = $_POST["stringParagraph"];         
$intNounCount = 0;
$intVerbCount= 0;
$intAdjCount = 0;
//check for user input
$stringNewStr = implode("",array($stringFirstVerb,$stringSecondVerb,
$stringThirdVerb,$stringFirstNoun,$stringSecondNoun,$stringThirdNoun,
$stringFirstAdj,$stringSecondAdj,$stringThirdAdj));   

var_dump($stringNewStr);

if( strpos($stringNewStr, ' ' ) !== false ){
echo "No spaces allowed in any Verbs, Nouns, or Adj's";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href="project1.html">Link to previous Page</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Personally I would use `strpos` over `preg_match`. Why use regular expressions if you can avoid them.

Comment: What does `var_dump` output?

Comment: I see you have a formatting / syntax error: `echo "<a href="project1.html">Link to previous Page</a>";` should be `echo "<a href=\"project1.html\">Link to previous Page</a>";`

Comment: @d3l  it outputs all of the words the user entered, consolidated into a single variable with no spaces. I am trying to check if this variable contains spaces/punctuation

Comment: I fixed my link error(thank you so much!), and it is still failing to compile

Comment: If it's "failing to compile" you should have an error somewhere. Try enabling error reporting temporarily in your script:

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @BT643   Thank you for your reply, I entered your code into my program and I am unable to see the issue. When I submit my form from the HTML page into the php program, it fails to load the page(Cannot connect to the server). I am just puzzled as to how such a simple statement is causing my program to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you call `strpos()`. You have a syntax error:

```
echo "<a href="project1.html">Link to previous Page</a>";
```

should be:

```
echo "<a href='project1.html'>Link to previous Page</a>";
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you for your response, I did not notice that minor syntax error. In my process of debugging I commented out all of the echo statements to isolate out the problem. It seems that the exact line that is breaking the program is the if statement. Even with this fix my php page still fails to load. I can post my entire code if it helps narrow down the issue.

Comment: @that would help, also if you could supply any error messages

Comment: Here is a link to my webpage which has all my code(cannot fit it all here). I have many syntax errors inside my code, however it is all commented out until I found a fix to this issue. http://104.239.192.194/~151_KELL135/public_html/project1/project1Code.txt

Comment: Also here is a link to my public HTML page which has my form, as well as my PHP page producing the error.    HTML Page- http://104.239.192.194/~151_KELL135/public_html/project1/project1.html            PHP page-http://104.239.192.194/~151_KELL135/public_html/project1/project1.php

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Are you a student?

Comment: Problem fixed. Thank you so much!